# Upgrading hibernate from 3.2.4.sp1 to a suitable version

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, java-7

Kindly provide some details which help to upgrade the hibernate version 3.2.4.sp1 to a suitable version.

We have already updated the Java runtime, Server OS and Database Server as well as some minor changes in the source code.

Following is the details of my Java Swing Application.

- Application uses Java web-start technology which communicates with the Servlets running on Tomcat 7.
- The Application is created some 8-9 years back. We keep on enhancing and bug fixing the application till date.
- DB is SQL Server 2012.
- Server Machine: Windows 64 bit 2008 R2 Enterprise Server
- Java 7 update 25 64 bit
- DB Driver: jtds-1.2
- Ehcache version 1.2.3

The observations are as follows:

- There is no ehcache.xml file int the project.
- We are not using any annotation in Entity class or any other parts in the application.
- Found that Ehcache 1.7.2 and above supports Java 1.5 and 1.6 at runtime.
- Found that the ehcache some times creates deadlock not sure about aver version but visit the following link: http://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/EHC-918.

Following is my hibernate.cfg.xml for reference:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<ip>:<port>/TestDB</property>
        <property name="connection.username">username</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</property> 
        <property name="c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
        <property name="c3p0.max_size">5</property> 
        <property name="c3p0.max_statements">0</property> 
        <property name="c3p0.min_size">3</property> 
        <property name="c3p0.timeout">20</property> <!-- seconds -->
        <property name="c3p0.idle_test_period">60</property> <!-- seconds --> 
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
        <property name="generate_statistics">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">somepackage.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
        <!-- Followed by our entity class mapping -->
        <mapping resource="Batch.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>  
</hibernate-configuration>
```

In this we are not specifying the second level hibernate cache, but I believe we are using some class in ehcache-1.2.3.jar as the cache provider since its there in the class path. When I go through the hibernate changelog I could see the default cache providers are different in some of the versions.

We are facing some performance and deadlock issue in current version of the application.

Kindly advice me a suitable version of hibernate so that I can upgrade to it without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.ranga</groupId>
<artifactId>HibernateApp2</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>HibernateApp2</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<!-- JBoss repository for Hibernate -->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>JBoss repository</id>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>                         
</dependencies>
```